# Access localStorage in iOS apps

Tags: ios, local-storage

I'm serving up remote html/javascript content into an iPad app. Javascript code runs great and html renders fine, but any attempt to access localStorage throws "Security_err: dom exception 18".

I was attempting to use localStorage because Safari by default won't accept third party cookies. Is there any way to set cookies or store values in localStorage from remote content to maintain state when served into an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old (and gaining dust), but here's an answer.

exception 18 is usually a cross domain permission issue.

consider one of the following solutions:

1. Instead of preloading the html string and then using `[myWebView loadHTMLString:str baseURL:url];`, just let the webview handle the whole request life cycle using `[myWebView loadRequest:someNSURLRequest];`
2. If your'e using Cordova, Edit your Cordova.plist file, add a new entry to the ExternalHosts list with the value * (please consider the [security compromise](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with this solution).